# Alert Dialog shows very slowly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I'm using Alert Dialog to show the custom view , but alert dialog comes very slowly. It approximately takes 10 or 15 seconds to show . Here  my code what is wrong in that .

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View vDialog = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setView(vDialog);
                AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
            ad.show();
```

Here my dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height ="match_parent" >

<CalendarView
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height ="50dp">        
</CalendarView>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,
    android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

dialog.xml
<CalendarView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height ="match_parent"/>

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
dialog.show();
```